# Hololens 2: Disable Windows Hello requirement

Tags: windows-authentication, hololens

My organization has purchased a number of Hololens 2 devices. These devices are shared, and need to support multiple users. However, when users log in, they are required to download a "Microsoft Authenicator app" on their personal phone and associate it with their company account. This is severely frowned upon. (Moreover, the hololens gives a QR code which must be scanned; rather difficult to scan an augmented reality QR code!)

How can we drop the requirement that users need to create a "Windows Hello" pin to use a Hololens 2?

(Strangely, I am able to dismiss the Windows Hello dialog box, but other users are not. Is this a clue to help us move forward?)

Comment: MS is the appropriate point of contact for this; if you have a corporate account then they should be able to help you out. Otherwise you're basically asking SO how to circumvent MS's licensing mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Well the easiest way to circumvent is to first log in and then reset the device and add a non corporate Microsoft account and share the details with your manager and dev ops person.

After adding a non-corporate account, you can remove the Window Hello and Pin things from the settings.